# Driver class can't load for first time

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc

I have one servlet class in which I established connection to `MySQL` database. This is my code for `doGet()` method.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
           //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");    
        con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","rspl123#");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    System.out.println(con);
    response.getWriter().write(request.getParameter("q"));

}
```

For above code, when the servlet is called for the first time, exception is thrown that `No suitable driver found`. But It runs and connection established successfully for the second time nd onwards.

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
at controller.FetchSuggestion.doGet(FetchSuggestion.java:44)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:261)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:581)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

null
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@1b83048
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@1455d1c
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@1f51e5c
```

The above code works fine if I remove the comment from `Class.forName()`, but it won't work without it for first time and able to establish connection for the second time onwards.
FYI : I already have MySQL JAVA connector in my class path.

MySQL Java Connector version : 5.1.10
JDK : 1.6
IDE : MyEclipse for Spring

Comment: Where is your Class.forName() code?

Comment: how exactly are you loading the driver? I mean you've to tell the application that you need to use MySQL driver. Can you tell us where that is being done?

Comment: I suppose, some other code is calling `Class.forName()` with the driver class name between your first and your second invocation.

Comment: No. I deleted Class.forName() code. But without Class.forName method, it should work.

Comment: Firstly: place the MySQL java drive jar file at you web project at WEB-INF/lib or if you use maven project, insert dependency in your project. Secondly: Add Complete code for connecting with databae.

Comment: @Holger : No, there is no other servlet in my program. I create seperate web project to check this problem.

Comment: @HarmeetSingh I already have it in my classpath. And what do you mean by `Complete code for connection with database?`

Comment: like where is you Class.forName(..) or some other code that is use for connect simple JDBC connection, the code is easily available from goggle . If you are using connection pool technique then there is a different way.

Comment: @HarmeetSingh You did'nt understand the question clearly. [Read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) this. It is clearly stated that `Applications no longer need to explictly load JDBC drivers using Class.forName()`

Comment: @VimalBera DataSource is the different way to Connect application with database. it is pooling concept. There are several way to implement data pooling concept. One Way is this [click] (http://harmeetsingh13.blogspot.in/2013/04/use-apache-dbcp-with-core-java.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of , you will need to include the `mysql-connector.jar`in your classpath. You can download the jar from:

- [MySQL Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j%20.)

You can then **configure your data source connection** using the following statements:

```
  // This will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
  try
  {
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  }
  catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
  {
  e.printStackTrace();
  }

  // Now you can setup the connection with the DB
   Connection connection=null;
   try {
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database","username", "password");
 } 
 catch (SQLException e) 
 {
    System.out.println("Connection Failed..!");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Registering the `DriverClassName` is a vital step**. Kindly do not skip it.

**EDIT:** I think I found your problem. Here's the analysis:

- The reason your application worked with `Class.forName` is because **you had specifically asked the `DriverManager` to load this Driver for you**.
- The reason that your application did not work for the first time is because you did not specify the Driver to be used.

Let me **elaborate on the second point**:

You are **absolutely right** in saying that the **application should work without `Class.forName`**. But aaahhh... **There's a catch**.

- When you **don't specify `Class.forName`** , the **DriverManager will try to load as many drivers as it can find and then for any given connection request, it will ask each driver in turn to try to connect to the target URL.**

This means that you **might have multiple Drivers in your application**. The **DriverManager found these drivers and tried to establish a connection to the database**. The **connection was null because the first driver found wasn't the right one**. But wait, **DriverManager is smart**. It knows **it could not connect to the database, so now it uses the other driver found**. And presto, the connection gets established.

Check the reference: [Driver Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html). It's mentioned in the documentation.

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: I already have MySQL Connector in class path. My question is `Without Class.forName(), why it didn't work for the first time?`

Comment: I fail to understand. Do you mean to ask `Why can you connect when you include Class.forName and not when I don't include it..?`. Meaning with Class.forName you are able to connect to the DB ..?

Comment: Yes,Without Class.forName() it SHOULD work fine. Because DriverManager has capability to search and load the driver by itself. See my stacktrace. First time it returns null. Why?

Comment: [Read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) this. `Applications no longer need to explictly load JDBC drivers using Class.forName().`

Comment: Hmmm. I see. Can you tell me what the line of code below the `System.out.Println(con)` does.?

Comment: @VimalBera: Turns out there is a line that says: `When the method getConnection is called, the DriverManager will attempt to locate a suitable driver from amongst those loaded at initialization and those loaded explicitly using the same classloader as the current applet or application.` Maybe the Driver isn't loaded at initialization and is found afterwards or you are using a different classloader perhaps..?

Comment: Also it's written that: `The driver should return "null" if it realizes it is the wrong kind of driver to connect to the given URL`. Maybe that is the case.

Comment: @VimalBera : Can you please follow up..?

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the source code for `java.sql.DriverManager` I see that the code for loading “initial” drivers (i.e. not explicitly loaded ones) is triggered by the first attempt to get a driver. If another thread tries to get a driver then, the `initialize()` method does not wait for the ongoing initialization but returns immediately:

```
static void initialize() {
    if (initialized) {
        return;
    }
    initialized = true;
    loadInitialDrivers();
    println("JDBC DriverManager initialized");
}
```

So it’s a race condition. The second thread will skip the initialization without finding a driver but surely complete before the first thread as not doing the initialization takes lesser time. So it appears as if the first attempt fails but it is the second.